# how to return to a number with a remainder

Tags: python, math, calculation

I'm trying to return to a number after dividing by 9 as follows:

[Division example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp94g.png)

Example: 12,500 / 9 = 1,388 (remainder 8) then dividing 1,388 / 9 will give 154 (remainder 2).

Now suppose I am left with 154 (remainder 2), I can calculate the next number in the chain as follows: (9x154) + 2 (remainder) which gives me 1,388 - is there a way to calculate the original (12,500) using 154 (remainder 2)?

Any workarounds will be appreciated

I would prefer solving using a calculation to get back to the original value

Comment: If you don't have a remainder of the first division (remainder 8), then no. If you do have it, then the same approach as you've used for the first number in the chain.

Comment: Other than 154 and the remainder 2 you'd also need the **previous** remainder, otherwise there are 9 possible numbers (since there are 9 possible remainders). Also I don't know how this is a programming question, this just looks like a mathematical question to me

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is just steps of base conversion. To convert 12500 to base-9, you need to keep dividing by 9 and collect the remainder, until the number is less than 9:

```
while n:
    n1, d = divmod(n, 9)
    print(f'{n} = {n1} * 9 + {d}')
    n = n1
```

```
12500 = 1388 * 9 + 8
1388 = 154 * 9 + 2
154 = 17 * 9 + 1
17 = 1 * 9 + 8
1 = 0 * 9 + 1
```

Base conversion:

```
def base_repr(n, base):
    s = ''
    while n:
        n, d = divmod(n, base)
        s = chr(d + (48 if d < 10 else 97)) + s
    return s
```

12500 in base-9:

```
base_repr(12500, 9)
#outputs 18128
```

To convert the number back, just do the reverse: use a initial value, for each remainder, keep multiplying the current value by 9 and add the current remainder, and assign the result to the current value:

```
for i in (1, 8, 1, 2, 8):
    n1 = n * 9 + i
    print(f'{n1} = {n} * 9 + {i}')
    n = n1
```

```
1 = 0 * 9 + 1
17 = 1 * 9 + 8
154 = 17 * 9 + 1
1388 = 154 * 9 + 2
12500 = 1388 * 9 + 8
```

Get numeric value:

```
def interpret_base(numeral, base):
    n = 0
    for s in numeral:
        n = n * base + (o := ord(s)) - (48 if o < 58 else 97)
    return n
```

To convert 18128<sub>9</sub> to decimal:

```
interpret_base('18128', 9)
#12500
```

To give non-zero initial value:

```
def interpret(numeral, base, ini=0):
    for s in numeral:
        ini = ini * base + (o := ord(s)) - (48 if o < 58 else 97)
    return ini
```

Then to get 12500 from 154 and 2, 8 remainders:

```
interpret('28', 9, 154)
#12500
```